# Libev, How to pass arguments to relevant callbacks

Tags: c, callback, libev

I'm trapped in a situation of argument passing in libev.

Usually, libev receives packages in a function like ***receive_callback***, that's OK, but in practice, we need to dispatch a relative ***write_callback*** to deal with specific jobs according to the received package. For example:

```
S_RECV_MSG* pstRecvMsg = (S_RECV_MSG*) recv_buff;
switch(pstRecvMsg->wMsgType) {
    case 1: 
        ev_io_init(w, write_callback1, w->fd, EV_WRITE);
        break;
    case 2:
        ev_io_init(w, write_callback2, w->fd, EV_WRITE);
        break;
    case 3:
        // .......
}
```

My question is, if the `write_callbackX` also has to read the specific content in the recv_buff, how can we pass the recv_buff argument to the callbackX? Must we bear the burden and ugliness of global variables here?

Comment: That is the correct answer, if you want to you can write it up as a real answer and accept it, makes it easier for other people to find the information.

Comment: At least you went back and kept researching rather than waiting around for an answer :)  Glad you solved it.

Comment: I suggest writing your solution as an answer (and then accept it) instead of editing it in the question

Answer (score 6):

The author answered it himself, but in a comment. Since this shows up as unanswered, I am
posting his answer in the "answer" section and closing the loop. Not sure if there is a better way... feel free to fix this.

Question author says:

> Sorry, I think I got the answer now, and feel deeply ashamed at my
>   carelessness of reading documentation:
>
> ```
> struct my_io{
>    ev_io io;
>    int otherfd;
>    void *somedata;
>    struct whatever *mostinteresting;
> };
> // ...
> struct my_io w;
> ev_io_init (&w.io, my_cb, fd, EV_READ);
> ```
>
> And then we use the my_io like this:
>
> ```
> static void my_cb (struct ev_loop *loop, ev_io *w_, int revents)
> {
>    struct my_io *w = (struct my_io *)w_;
>    //...
> }
> ```

Comment: if i'm using heap memory in somedata, what is the correct approach to free it?

Comment: I don't get it. How can ev_io* w_ be cast into (struct my_io*) in the my_cb callback?

Comment: @lppier The `ev_io` is the first member in `my_io` so its address can be obtained by that cast.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's explained in libev document, and there is another way. Each watcher has a void *data member that you can read or modify, and libev will completely ignore it, so you can pass the argument like this:

```
w->data = (void *)recv_buff;
...
static void my_cb (struct ev_loop *loop, ev_io *w_, int revents)
{
    S_RECV_MSG *recv_buff = (S_RECV_MSG*)w_->data;
    ...
}
```

see [libev document](http://pod.tst.eu/http://cvs.schmorp.de/libev/ev.pod#ASSOCIATING_CUSTOM_DATA_WITH_A_WATCH).

Comment: using ->data is a munch nicer way of doing it than the 'subclassing' technique